# Efficiency Issue in the following data transfer technique via Socket communication

Tags: java, sockets

I've been facing this issue for very long time to implement the following scenario with a good practice. And I'm having issues. Suggest me or guide me if I went wrong somewhere. Details as follows.
1) I've a PLC that acts as a server socket program. And I have a Java Client Socket program to read the data from the Server.
Since here PLC is the Server, It establishes a passive communication and when the client initiates the communication, Server provides client the data from a specific area which look the below
[image: Kishore Kumar Korada]

As you can see in the image, For each read, Client program should get all the data from first byte to last byte from the Server Sending area. And as per the offset and length that Client program was provided, It process the data and store it into the database.

**Note:** Each time, Client program should get the similar data with same offsets and length. 
2) I unsure of if I could achieve this with a single socket connection(Tried but didn't get expected result), was reading the data from the server, processing it, storing it in db then **Closing the Socket**. And Re-creating the socket again. And I'm doing this in every 1 second interval. **Which means I'm creating a lot of sockets.**
Overall structure can be descried pictorially as below
[image: Kishore Kumar Korada] 
3) Client code I've used to get the data from the server is below

```
try {
    socket = new Socket(host, port);
    is = socket.getInputStream();
    outputBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    if((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputBuffer.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    /* All Processing work */
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        System.out.println("Before closing the socket");
        try {
            is.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("After closing the socket");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm closing the sockets as you can see here. And I've been running the same code snippet for every second in a scheduler.
By having all this structure, I would like to ask following questions
1) Can I get the same data as you can see in the **first picture** with a single socket connection every time when it gets enabled for me to read???
If yes, Could be explain briefly?
2) Is my Code snippet looks as a Client Socket Program? I know I've closed the socket in there. Actually like I said before, I've been executing the same code for every 1 second. If it's not a good practice, Could you suggest me one?
3) Over all, by looking into the second picture, how to achieve the same data from sending area again and again with same offset?

Comment: There are [**timeout** possibilities(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), but at least develop a version which always closes, as an open connection has more border cases, is harder to diagnose. I think.

Comment: @JoopEggen
Yes I've seen timeouts.
Also I've been closing sockets from the client program and recreating it. With I'm i'm to get what I want i.e getting the data as it is in first image.
But I'm re-creating a socket for data availability for every 1 second span, This is where I'm getting worried.

Comment: Throw it all away and use a `DataOutputStream` wrapped around a `BufferedOutputStream` wrapped around the socket output stream. Converse at the other end. Flush the `DataOutputStream` when you switch from writing to reading.

Comment: It sounds like the PLC server can only send data to a client as a response to a newly accepted socket from a client, and this is something outside your control?  If so, this clearly limits options, but if the PLC is sending the same data to every client, regardless of where they connect from, an intermediate (proxy style) server might be the solution.  This would need to poll the PLC as a client, but other clients could maintain their connections to this 'proxy' and listen to a continuous stream of data, possibly with extra separators/length counters between the 'packets'.

Comment: If your local network is OK with it, and the packet size is predictably small enough, the 'proxy' server could even use [multicast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html).  This is quite efficient for repeated one second transmissions, where occasional packet loss is tolerable.  Happy to sketch out either approach, if it sounds like it's on the right lines.

Comment: @df778899 Yes I've no control over PLC.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Can I get the same data as you can see in the first picture with a single socket connection every time when it gets enabled for me to read??? If yes, Could be explain briefly?

You *can*, but I wouldn't recommend it. Because you're receiving a fixed amount of data every second and processing it immediately after, I would opt to have one thread tasked with reading the data from the socket, and another thread (or pool of threads) tasked with processing the incoming data. If processing the data takes longer than one second and you process it on the same thread as the `Socket`, data will become backed up very quickly.

> 2) Is my Code snippet looks as a Client Socket Program? I know I've closed the socket in there. Actually like I said before, I've been executing the same code for every 1 second. If it's not a good practice, Could you suggest me one?

Client/Server programs can vary in many ways, so there's no *correct* standard. Regarding alternative solutions, see what I wrote above.

> 3) Over all, by looking into the second picture, how to achieve the same data from sending area again and again with same offset?

Luckily for you, I created and maintain a client/server *framework* called [SimpleNet](https://github.com/jhg023/SimpleNet), which I think would make this a lot easier!

Example code for your program using SimpleNet would look like the following:

```
Client client = new Client();

client.onConnect(() -> {
    // Continuously read 52 bytes of data and invoke the callback when they arrive.
    client.readAlways(52, buffer -> {
        int realValue = buffer.getInt();  // 4 bytes
        int intValue = buffer.getShort(); // 2 bytes

        byte[] operatorNameBytes = new byte[18];
        buffer.get(operatorNameBytes);
        String operatorName = new String(operatorNameBytes);

        byte[] shiftIdBytes = new byte[10];
        buffer.get(shiftIdBytes);
        String shiftId = new String(shiftIdBytes);

        byte[] productIdBytes = new byte[16];
        buffer.get(productIdBytes);
        String productId = new String(productIdBytes);

        int status = buffer.getShort(); // 2 bytes

        // All processing work can occur here or be delegated to a thread pool.
    });
});

client.connect(host, port);
```

By keeping the connection to the server open, I think it would end up being less expensive than having to constantly create and destroy `Socket` objects. Also, the asynchronous callbacks that SimpleNet uses should enable it to be scalable if you ever decide to send more data in.

**Note**: Assuming that your server sends data to the client once per second, then the example will work for you without having to change anything. Otherwise, you can change `client.readAlways` to `client.read` and use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to invoke `client.read` once per second. If your server only sends data to a client when they first connect, then you can also use `client.read` and just reconnect the client once per second.